# How to recreate FragmentManager#getFragments() behavior from Android Support Library 25.3.0

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app uses `FragmentManager#getFragments()` method:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments()

Everything was fine but when I updated Android Support Library from 25.3.0 to 25.4.0 version it stopped working. In 25.4.0 `getFragments()` method no longer returns all fragments:

> Get a list of all fragments that are currently added to the FragmentManager. This may include those that are hidden as well as those that are shown. This will not include any fragments only in the back stack, or fragments that are detached or removed.

Previously:

> Get a list of all fragments that are currently added to the FragmentManager.

Public `getFragments()` method content was replaced and the old body was moved to package-private `getActiveFragments()` method. I can invoke it via reflection but this solution seems super hacky. I wonder if there is a better solution.

```
public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    if(this.mAdded.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    } else {
        ArrayList var1 = this.mAdded;
        synchronized(this.mAdded) {
            return (List)this.mAdded.clone();
        }
    }
}

List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
    if(this.mActive == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int count = this.mActive.size();
        ArrayList fragments = new ArrayList(count);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            fragments.add(this.mActive.valueAt(i));
        }

        return fragments;
    }
}
```

So my question is:
**Is there a way to recreate FragmentManager#getFragments() behavior from 25.3.0 version?**